# How to filter FlatMap based on null value

Tags: scala, graph, apache-spark, vertices

I am generating graph using following code.

NOTE:- raw(1) = name, raw(2) = type

```
 val Nodes: RDD[(VertexId, (String, String))] = sc.textFile(nodesFile).flatMap {
  line =>
    if (!line.isEmpty && line(0) != '#') {
      val row = line.split(";,;,;")
      if (row.length == 3) {
        if (row(0).length > 0 && row(1).length > 0 && row(2).length > 0 && row(0).forall(_.isDigit) && row(2).toString.toUpperCase != "AB" && row(2).toString.toUpperCase != "XYZ") {
          List((row(0).toLong, (row(1).toString.toUpperCase, row(2).toString.toUpperCase)))
        } else { None }
      } else { None }
    } else {
      None
    }
}
```

So It's generating map like this.

```
(11,(SAMSUNG_PHONE,Item))
(0,null)
(1,(Flying,PC))
(6,null)
```

Means Vertices 0 and 6 have with value is 'AB' or 'XYZ'. that's why it's inserting null but i want to filter and want to remove this null value node.. I tried but didn't get it.

Please give me hint or reference.

Comment: Could you show your input data?

Comment: .filter(x=>(x._2 != null))?

Answer (score 3):

## A Solution

Assuming an input file with content

```
0;foo;AB
1;cool,stuff
2;other;things
6;foo;XYZ
3;a;b
```

your code is nearly working.

After **adapting the split pattern** (see below) and **polishing the return value** (List() instead of None) the code works:

```
configuredUnitTest("Test SO") { sc =>
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  val nodesFile = "/home/martin/input.txt"

  val nodes: RDD[(Long, (String, String))] = sc.textFile(nodesFile).flatMap {
    line =>
      if (!line.isEmpty && line(0) != '#') {
        val row = line.split("[,;]")
        if (row.length == 3) {
          if (row(0).length > 0 && row(1).length > 0 && row(2).length > 0 && row(0).forall(_.isDigit) && row(2).toString.toUpperCase != "AB" && row(2).toString.toUpperCase != "XYZ") {
            List((row(0).toLong, (row(1).toString.toUpperCase, row(2).toString.toUpperCase)))
          } else {
            List()
          }
        } else {
          List()
        }
      } else {
        List()
      }
  }

  println( nodes.count() )

  val result = nodes.collect()
  println( result.size )
  println( result.mkString("\n") )
}
```

Result is

```
3
3
(1,(COOL,STUFF))
(2,(OTHER,THINGS))
(3,(A,B))
```

### Code deficiencies

#### Return type of function String => List[Long, (String, String)]

Your code for rejecting non matching lines is verbose and unreadable. Why don't you return a `List()` instead of `None`. Example that proofs:

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> a.flatMap( x => { if (x==1) List() else List(x)} )
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

Having said, ***you don't need to use `flatmap` and filter for `null` values***

#### Split pattern

Your regex split pattern is **wrong**.

Your pattern ";,;,;" says: Split when encountering the sequence ";,;,;", thus "a;,;,;b" is split into a and b. This is most probably **not** what you want. Instead, you want to split at either ";" or ",", so the rexex saying ";" or "," is "[;,]".

```
scala> val x ="a;b,c"
x: String = a;b,c

scala> x.split(";").mkString("|")
res2: String = a|b,c

scala> x.split(";,").mkString("|")
res3: String = a;b,c

scala> x.split("[;,]").mkString("|")
res4: String = a|b|c
```

## A much better approach

With `filter` and some helper functions, your code can be rewritten as

```
configuredUnitTest("Test SO") { sc =>
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  val nodesFile = "/home/martin/input.txt"

  def lengthOfAtLeastOne(x: String) : Boolean = x.length > 0
  def toUpperCase(x: String) = x.toString.toUpperCase

  val nodes = sc.textFile(nodesFile)
    .map( _.split("[;,]") )
    .filter( _.size == 3 )
    .filter( xs => ( lengthOfAtLeastOne(xs(0)) && lengthOfAtLeastOne(xs(1)) && lengthOfAtLeastOne(xs(2)) ) )
    .filter( xs => (toUpperCase(xs(2)) != "AB") && (toUpperCase(xs(2)) != "XYZ"))
    .map( xs => (xs(0).toLong, ( toUpperCase(xs(1)), toUpperCase(xs(2))) ))

  println( nodes.count() )

  val result = nodes.collect()
  println( result.size )
  println( result.mkString("\n") )

  println("END OF")
}
```

*Much better to **read**, eh?*

Comment: It looks like you've lost `row(0).forall(_.isDigit)` predicate somewhere on the way. I would replace the first filter with  `!xs.take(3).exists(_.isEmpty)`. Finally `toUpperCase` function seems obsolete. It is simply `x.toUpperCase`. So the second predicate is `!List("AB", "XYZ").contains(xs(2).toUpperCase)` and can be replaced with regex to make it more efficient on longer patterns: `"(?i)^(AB|XYZ)$".r.findFirstIn(xs(2)).isDefined`

Comment: It giving me 0 node count and following output (4,null)
(13,null)
(16,null)
(19,null)
(14,null)
(15,null)
(0,null)
(11,null)
(6,null)
(8,null)
(12,null)
(10,null)
(1,null)
(2,null)
(17,null)
(3,null)
(7,null)
(9,null)
(5,null)

Comment: See the input file I have used. The code exactly produces the proper result shown. So I asssume your input file is different. Let us know its content ...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it seems to work just fine.
I've used the input from [Martin Senne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211082/martin-senne), and also used his regex.
Because I don't know exactly what `textFile` is, I just read some lines from a file

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("so/resources/f").getLines.toList

val x = lines.flatMap {
  line =>
    if (!line.isEmpty && line(0) != '#') {
      val row = line.split("[;,]")
      if (row.length == 3) {
        if (row(0).length > 0 && row(1).length > 0 && row(2).length > 0 && row(0).forall(_.isDigit) && row(2).toString.toUpperCase != "AB" && row(2).toString.toUpperCase != "XYZ") {
          List((row(0).toLong, (row(1).toString.toUpperCase, row(2).toString.toUpperCase)))
        } else {
          None
        }
      } else {
        None
      }
    } else {
      None
    }
}

println(x.size)
x foreach println
```

So for this input:

```
0;foo;AB
1;cool,stuff
2;other;things
6;foo;XYZ
3;a;b
```

I got this output:

```
3
(1,(COOL,STUFF))
(2,(OTHER,THINGS))
(3,(A,B))
```

Of course, there can be added many modification to your code:

```
.filterNot(_.startsWith("#")) // lines cannot start with #
      .map(_.split("[;,]")) // split the lines
      .filter(_.size == 3)  // each line must have 3 items in it
      .filter(line => line.filter(_.length > 0).size == 3) // and none of those items can be empty ***
      .filter(line => line(2).toUpperCase != "AB" ) // also those that have AB
      .filter(line => line(2).toUpperCase != "XYZ" ) // also those that have XYZ
      .map(line => (line(0).toLong, (line(1).toUpperCase, line(2).toUpperCase))) // the final format
```

---

*** this:

```
.filter(line => line.filter(_.length > 0).size == 3)
```

can also be written like this:

```
.map(_.filter(_.length > 0)) // each item must not be empty
.filter(_.size == 3)  // so the lines with less than 3 items will be removed; ***
```

Also, as an observation, you don't have to put `toString` alongside a `String`.